# Cannot install any R package

Tags: r, libclang

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04. R version 4.0.2.
I've been using R for a long time and everything worked fine.
Today, when trying to install new packages i get this error:

```
** checking absolute paths in shared objects and dynamic libraries
readelf: symbol lookup error: readelf: undefined symbol: ctf_arc_bufopen, version LIBCTF_1.0
Error in system(paste("readelf -d", shQuote(l)), intern = TRUE) :
  error in running command
```

I tried to delete and reinstall R and all the packages, but now the same thing happens also for packages that were previously installed. So i think that the problem is not caused by R itself.
I havent done any R update recently.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. what is the output of `readelf --help` in a terminal? I would say your software building tool chain wants updating .  I note your `libclang` tag and don't know if [ctf-suite](https://www.illumos.org/issues/12230) applies. I generally allow `GCC` to do my building unless libclang is required. HTH

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! The output is `readelf: symbol lookup error: readelf: undefined symbol: ctf_arc_bufopen, version LIBCTF_1.0`

Comment: Yes, I read that part above. I meant, when you open up a terminal and type `readelf --help`, what shows up in your terminal as output.

Comment: Yes. The line I wrote in the comment before is exactly the output of the command

Comment: Ok, close R or RStudio, because as you say above, it isn't R. Open a terminal, and try `your_prompt:~$ dpkg -l | grep libctf*`, which might report `ii  libctf-nobfd0:amd64                                         2.34-6ubuntu1.1                                                 amd64        Compact C Type Format library (runtime, no BFD dependency)
ii  libctf0:amd64                                               2.34-6ubuntu1.1 `, or not. Do same for `readelf --help`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thank you very much [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/794450/chris) for hinting at the problem. It was actually `ctf-suite` related.
When doing `grep libctf*` it returned:

```
ii  libctf0:amd64                                    2.35.1-1ubuntu1
amd64        Compact C Type Format library (runtime, BFD dependency)
```

So I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install libctf-nobfd0
```

and it actually solved the problem.
I managed to install all the needed packages.